# SQLITE3 Python updating a record with variables not working?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Within my sql statements, I am trying to add 2 values to a record where the id of this record equals a certain number. All 3 of these values are variables. I am getting an error of "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SET": syntax error".

Any clue to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
self.db = sqlite3.connect("aLevelTracker.db")
self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
if self.typeOfAccount=="student":
    self.cursor.execute("UPDATE student SET username = ? AND SET password = ? WHERE student_id = ?",((self.username),(self.passwordHash),(self.lastID)))
if self.typeOfAccount=="teacher":
    self.cursor.execute("UPDATE teacher SET username=? AND SET password = ? WHERE teacher_id = ?",((self.username),(self.passwordHash),(self.lastID)))
self.db.commit()
self.db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `AND`:

```
"UPDATE student SET username = ?, password = ? WHERE student_id = ?"

"UPDATE teacher SET username=?, password = ? WHERE teacher_id = ?"
```